# iOS 10 requestAuthorization

Tags: swift3, ios10, mpmedialibrary

I don't know what's the wrong with this code, it always shows me this thing:`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
I got that thing when I try to get access to `MPMediaLibrary`, the code is this:

```
if (MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {

            // Access has not been determined.
            MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus) in

                if (status == MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                    let albumsQuery: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.albums()
                    let albumItems: [MPMediaItemCollection] = self.albumsQuery.collections! as [MPMediaItemCollection]
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Test optionals instead of force unwrapping them.

Comment: @Phillip Mills I didn't understand, my english is week and I'm new to swift :)

Comment: Study Swift optionals.  You really need to understand them to use the language.  For your case, when you use `!` you are saying that you promise the variable is non-nil.  If you break that promise, your app crashes with the message you mention.

Comment: When I press on allow it shows me that error, but we I relaunch the app the error gone, the code I have used is that: `if (status == .authorized) {
            // Access has been granted.
            let albumItems: [MPMediaItemCollection] = albumsQuery.collections! as [MPMediaItemCollection]
            
            if albumItems.isEmpty == false{
                print("here 1")
            }`

Comment: Don't use `!`.  Test whether `.collections` actually has a valid value.

Comment: It doesn't accept that it always ask me to use `!`

Comment: Hint: `if let albumItems = albumsQuery.collections {  } else {  }`

Comment: It shows me `nil` when I launch the app for first time 

Comment: I don't know **why** it's nil, but that's why it was crashing when you forced it with `!`.

Comment: Thank you @PhillipMills for your help, I appreciate that 